# Filtering eloquent collection with foreign table's attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a users table and I am trying to return the data to a view after filtering the collection with its foreign table (user_details) by the attribute where "status" = "1".

I have researched and tried many method suggested online such as

```
$users = Users::whereHas('details_id', function($query) {
    $query->where('status', '1');
})->get()->paginate(15);
```

But I am getting an error of

> Call to undefined method App\Models\User::details_id()

This is my User's model below: -

```
public function user_details() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserDetails::class, "id");
}
```

Comment: Try:

`$users = Users::all()->get(); dd($users);`
then
`$users = Users::all()->with('user_details_table_name_here')->get(); dd($users);`
see how results differ.

Comment: Which table has `details_id`? In fact, would you be able to show the column names for both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `has` or `whereHas` you should use the name of the relationship (the method name) not the field name that relates them:

```php
$users = Users::whereHas('user_details', function($query) {
    $query->where('status','1');
})->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Ohhh thanks ! I am one step further but now I am getting an error of "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist." and my pagination doesnt work

Comment: @zernzern1993 I've updated the code. Sorry, I should have looked at all of it. When calling `paginate` you shouldn't use `get` as well. Also, are you able to tell me where `details_id` comes in to it? I think your relationship might not be set up correctly.

Comment: Omg you're a lifesaver !!! It's working now, err the details_id is a foreign key attribute in the User's table pointing to a certain row in the UserDetails table if you're still wondering ! Thanks a lot btw !!

Comment: @zernzern1993 If it's working then it shouldn't matter but really the `user_details` relationship should be a `belongsTo`. Rule of thumb is if the `*_id` column in in that table it's a `belongsTo`.

Comment: Ohhh I see I get what you mean now ! I shall change it ! thanks again mate !